# how can i solve flutter path provider debug error

Tags: android, flutter

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider:parseDebugLibraryResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`
how can i solve flutter debug error "path_provider parse Debug Library Resources". i upgraded everything and included the "path_provider" dependency. tell me how i can solve this problem.